# Is the Andreev-Bashkin effect a beyond-mean-field effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, quasiparticles

I am reading about the Andreev-Bashkin effect, which concerns the current drag from the interaction between two superfluids. Basically, the interaction between two coupled superfluids leads to the formation of quasi-particles with nonzero content of either of the two species. Therefore, the transport properties of the two components are not independent: the mass ﬂow of one component must be accompanied by mass transport of the other component.

See the very good References:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1134/S106377610707028X.pdf
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aa93a0

My question is: does this effect originate from a mean-field treatment of two coupled superfluids (two coupled Gross-Pitaevskii equations)? Or, instead, is it a beyond-mean-field effect, since it involves the creation of composite quasiparticles carrying the mass of both species?

In other words: is it possible to "observe" the Andreev-Bashkin effect just by resorting to two coupled Gross-Pitaevskii equations or is it necessary to employ fully-quantum approaches?